# Razor: adding variable in loop without displaying it

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, loops, razor, foreach

Hi I am wondering how do I add numbers without displaying them while in foreach loop
expamle:

```
@{ int intVariable = 0; }

@foreach(var item in @Model.Collection)
{
    @(intVariable += item.MyNumberOfInteres) //->how can I calculate this without it being rendered to the website ?

    //some Html code.......
}
```

Can anybody help ?

cheers
sushiBite

Comment: try to make this at first few line and quote everything with 
@{

Do everything here 

}

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You replace parenthesis with curly brackets and add a trailing semicolon:

```
@(intVariable += item.MyNumberOfInteres)
```

becomes:

```
@{ intVariable += item.MyNumberOfInteres; }
```

This being said you shouldn't be doing things like this in a view. If you need to do it, this simply means that your view model is not adapted to your view. So adapt it. This kind of information should have been directly integrated in the view model and calculated in the controller.

Remember: the view is there only to display data that it is being passed from the controller under the form of a view model. If a view begins to calculate variables and stuff it no longer resembles to a view but spaghetti code.

Comment: This deserves about 20 votes, unfortunately SO only gives me 1.

Comment: Sure, but this answer is incorrect. The answer from Dan Diplo is correct.

Rory, when you start your loop, you are in code mode. Until Razor sees an HTML tag, it will stay in code mode.  The reason it's not working for you in your example is because of the @.  When you're already in code mode, the parser then flips back to markup mode and assumes you want to render whatever is after the @ (to the end of the statement).  Make sense?

Comment: Sometimes you need to do some code or calculations related to the view (ie, displaying the items in rows of 3 items). That kind of calculations are related only to the view, and have nothing to do with the controller or the model.

Comment: @EduardoMolteni, I agree that they have nothing to do with the controller or the model. That's why this should be done in the view model as I suggested in my answer. That's what view models should be designed for.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov yes I think I should probably fix my model (it was just to do the adding in the view :/

Comment: I do get a warning in visual studio that the curly braces aren't normally expected in the body of the code, just in the header.

Comment: in fact it throws an exception:
Unexpected "{" after "@" character. Once inside the body of a code block (@if {}, @{}, etc.) you do not need to use "@{" to switch to code.

Comment: Ok, it's inside the body of the foreach loop, so can remove the @ etc. Doh! works now

Answer (score 17):

Remove the @ and prefix with a semicolon ie.

```
intVariable += item.MyNumberOfInteres;
```

Comment: The accepted solution does not work in .net core 6.  It tells me I can't use `{ }` when i'm already inside one.  This works and was surprisingly simple.  Thanks!